# Why is it so hard to show the URL of the current category and how to do it?

Tags: categories, link-category

If I'm on a singular page, it is quite easy to show the current post URL outside the loop:

```
the_permalink();
```

If I am on a category page it is quite simple to show the category description outside the loop:

```
category_description();
```

Unless I'm missing something, it is not equally easy to show the current category URL outside the loop - which is strange.

`echo get_category_link();` - doesn't work like this.

I need to use my category URL in the `<head>`, for canonical link, og:url etc. How can I do that?

I did read [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/48435/get-term-archive-url-link) and found that you have to create a new function just to show the current category. Is there any other way to do it?

```
/**
 * Pass in a taxonomy value that is supported by WP's `get_taxonomy`
 * and you will get back the url to the archive view.
 * @param $taxonomy string|int
 * @return string
 */
function get_taxonomy_archive_link( $taxonomy ) {
  $tax = get_taxonomy( $taxonomy ) ;
  return get_bloginfo( 'url' ) . '/' . $tax->rewrite['slug'];
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On a category archive, `get_queried_object_id()` will give you the category's ID, which you can pass to `get_category_link()`:

```
echo get_category_link( get_queried_object_id() );
```

Comment: This works! Thank you. You'd be amazed to know that all over the web I have searched, people are creating new functions to show the category url. Your solution is simple and elegant.